# How do I create a view to DISPLAY ALL EVENTS

Tags: civievent

it looks like the Events Dashboard only shows upcoming events.
As I am using Civi to Manage membership and attendance to events, I would like to easily access all past events in order to edit participant lists, etc.
HOW DO I DO THIS?
And is there a reason why the events dashboard does not offer the choice of showing events?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackExchange Daniel. You are probably talking about this view: Events > Dashboard, which indeed only shows upcoming events and recents registrations.

There is another page, Events > Manage Events, that allows you to search and filter for events or show all events including past ones.

[image: Manage Events interface]

You could of course also create a report to list all (relevant) events and/or participants.

Comment: To make things more intuitive for your requirements, you could also disable some of the menu items (such as Event Dashboard), and have Manage Events at the top of the Events menu. They can be customized from Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Navigation Menu.